# Eggnog to Spirit ratio?

Tags: alcohol, alcohol-content

I know, I know, I should be making my own eggnog, but when I'm in a pinch and I don't have the time to make my own eggnog, I have to rely on the store bought stuff.

With that being said, can anyone tell me a standard ratio of eggnog to brandy/rum?

Comment: Depends on how much you like your relatives...

Comment: Many people would choose a ratio of zero to one.

Comment: Why do people knock store-bought egg nog all the time? IMNSHO, it's the best stuff on Earth.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is no standard, it all depends on how happy you want to get, and whether you just want the flavor of the booze, or the actual effect of the alcohol. Also a factor is the kind of alcohol you want to add. Light rums, for example, have less flavor than dark rums, so you'd want to use dark rum if you want booze flavor over alcohol.

As an estimate if you are going for flavor an ounce or two per liter (or quart, they're close enough for jazz) will do the trick, or up to 6 or 8 if you want very happy people.

Don't forget to grate a bit of fresh nutmeg on top before serving!

Answer (score 2):

I used a store bought large carton (64 oz) and 8 oz light rum.  It was good and not too strong.  People could add additional rum individually to their glass if they wanted stronger

Answer (score 2):

We flavor our egg nog individually. About 1/2 to 1 oz per large coffee mug full. I like store bought egg nog. We have made it before. It's expensive and requires multiple ingredients.
We add nutmeg on the top. Ground nutmeg from the can works just fine.

Answer (score -1):

I bought some really good eggnog today and mixed it with a ratio of one third cup brandy to two thirds cup eggnog. No one got crazy and it was delicious.